# Calculate mathematical functions in iron python

Tags: ironpython

How do I calculate cosine or sine in iron python?  I think this is the code that needs to be used.

```
costheta = math.cos(float(theta))
sintheta = math.sin(float(theta))
```

But, what are the directories that need to be included?

Comment: Are you asking whether your should `import math`? If not, could you elaborate the question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "cmath" [cmath ironpython reference](https://ironpython-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/cmath.html#module-cmath)

Answer (score 0):

got the answer..
it is just adding 'import math' at the start of program and using math.cos